# How to get MySQL group_concat fields as columns using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query running that currently groups fields in a `<td>` using `group_concat`.

I am trying to get each `custom_field_id` as a column with `value` as the `<td>` output using php.

Here is a sqlfiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88d80/3

Here is a sample of the output I am looking for.

```
user_id      |     first_name     |    last_name     |  custom_field_3  |   custom_field_5  |   custom_field_7  |   custom_field_9  |   custom_field_11     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            |     Jeff           |    Smith         |  XXXX            |   BBBB            |   CCCC            |   ZZZZ            |   YYYY                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2            |     Bob            |    Smith         |  XXXX            |   BBBB            |   CCCC            |   ZZZZ            |   YYYY                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3            |     Steve          |    Smith         |  XXXX            |   BBBB            |   CCCC            |   ZZZZ            |   YYYY                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4            |     Mary           |    Smith         |  XXXX            |   BBBB            |   CCCC            |   ZZZZ            |   YYYY                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5            |     Anna           |    Smith         |  XXXX            |   BBBB            |   CCCC            |   ZZZZ            |   YYYY                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is each user_id guaranteed to have a value for each of the custom fields? That is, are all of the GROUP_CONCAT() results guaranteed to have the same number of elements?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski no there are some users with no fields, and some with empty fields.